# cov-commit-defects failed with Preparing to load derived models in Jenkins windows node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, coverity

I am unable to do commit coverity after coverity analysis

I have analysed using "C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis"\bin\cov-analyze.exe --dir Y:\myPath\imdir

"C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis"\bin\cov-commit-defects.exe --dir Y:\myPath\imdir --host coverity.personal.com --port 8080 --stream testing --encryption required --auth-key-file "C:\Program Files\Coverity\Coverity Static Analysis"\config\auth-key.txt --on-new-cert trust --description description

```
09:56:34  Connecting to server coverity.personal.com:9090
09:56:35  Connection is encrypted.
09:56:37  Elapsed time: 00:00:02
09:56:37  Preparing to load derived models: cannot read Y:/myPath/imdir/output/models.j: open: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Path `Y:/myPath/imdir/output/models.j` looks like linux path where models.j does not exist and we have models file.
Any input on this will be very useful

Answer (score 0):

`Y:\myPath` is the shared drive, I moved to the system drive(Ex: `C:\myPath`) to place source and run coverity solved the issue.